# Can a Single Query give results for conditional outcomes in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, join, repository

I am facing an issue where I want multiple results to be displayed using a single query rather than multiple queries.

Lets say a Table have 50 Records and 3 Columns, 1 column may be required may not be. When user keeps it null Query1 returns 30 records when user gives some value to it Query2 will return 15 records. Can this be achieved using one query only?

Controller:

```
public Iterable<Number> getNumberRecords(@PathVariable String one, @PathVariable String two,
                                          @RequestParam(value = "three", required = false) String three) {

if(three == null)
   return numberRepository.findAllbyOneAndTwo(one,two);
else
   return numberRepository.findAllbyOneAndTwoAndThree(one,two,three);
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface NumberRepository extends CrudRepository<Number, Long>{

List<Number> findAllbyOneAndTwoAndThree(String one, String two, String three);
List<Number> findAllbyOneAndTwo(String one, String two);

}
```

I want only one query that will satisfy and give expected output in both the cases. A conditional Query using **@Query(" ")** will also do.

Comment: `List<? extends Number> findAllByOneAndTwoAndThree(String one, String two, @Nullable String three);`?  (I.e. just accept a `null` value for that `String` (which is what spring will provide if one _isn't_ supplied.)  Then you can just have your code build the query `String` as is, with an `if (three != null) { queryBuilder.append(" AND WHERE a.someProperty = :three"); }` (or something to that effect).  (I've assumed `queryBuilder` is a `StringBuilder` or something similar, but do whatever you want for appending to the query.)

Comment: @BeUndead if I keep Three Null The result will be Null because its an AND operation and if I do OR operation, when Three is actually given a value it will just give all cases where three is present.

Comment: The code I added in the comment covers this.  You only add the clause to the query `if (three != null)`.

Answer (score 0):

To convert my comment to an answer, something like the following should cover what you're talking about:

```java
public List<? extends Number> findAllByOneTwoAndThree(final String one,
                                                      final String two,
                                                      final @Nullable String three) {
    final StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    queryBuilder.append("SELECT x FROM some_table x")
            .append(" WHERE x.one = :one")
            .append(" AND x.two = :two");

    if (three != null) {
        // Only add to the query if three was NOT null.
        queryBuilder.append(" AND x.three = :three");
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: You cannot add a body to Interface abstract methods.. :(

Comment: Look up `default` methods :)